# Creating array by Object (and vice versa) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

*What is going on here?*

```
var x = {length:3, '0':'foo', '1':'bar','2':'f', splice:function(){}}
```

This actually creates an array:

```
["foo", "bar", "f"]
```

Where is the documentation for this structure syntax?

It's also smart:

changing to: (notice 0 , 1 , 3)

```
 var x = {length:3, '0':'foo', '1':'bar','3':'f', splice:function(){}}
```

will mess up the array and it will be:

```
["foo", "bar", undefined × 1]
```

Also, removing the splice function:

```
var x = {length:3, '0':'foo', '1':'bar','2':'f'}
```

yields:  (regular object)

```
Object
0: "foo"
1: "bar"
2: "f"
length: 3
__proto__: Object
```

So I have two questions:

- What is this structure?   `length , element , splice`
- Say I have `['john','paul','yoko']` and now I want to create the *object*

  `var x = {length:3, '0':'john', '1':'paul','2':'yoko', splice:function(){}}`

  How would I do this?

Comment: *this actually creats an array*, why? Because the console shows it as an array? Probably just some optimised test. `x.constructor` gives `function Object() ...`.

Comment: Yoshi you got a point : `Object.prototype.toString.apply(x)` = 
`"[object Object]"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**An array is nothing else than an object**, with some methods implemented, when you make `console.log(x)`, your console recognizes the model of an array, and display it like it has been configured to do so.

`Array` is an object available by default in *Javascript*, and it is handled a bit differently than other objects by the browser (see @MathiasSchwarz comment), but in its structure, it is an object like the others (there's methods that you can call, and you can add indexes. Though, you don't usually use string indexes like in "normal" objects, because it's not aimed to be used like that).

But your object is not really an `Array`, you can do whatever you want without referring to what is displayed in the console.

Comment: why the splice func is there ?

Comment: That is not entirely correct. Arrays are a special kind of objects. The printing behavior is simply caused by the fact that an array has a `toString` method. Such a method could easily be implemented by a programmer as well. The special thing about arrays is the `length` field which is automatically updated when the array is updated. Such a field cannot be implemented by a programmer, so it is indeed more than an object...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Thats because the console recognises it as an array by looking if there are `length` and `splice` fields in it (IMO).

Comment: You can have string indexes inside an Array. They just don't count towards the `length`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, I edited my post. I think arrays have been created to be used with number indexes to be able to browse them with a integer variable, and that was what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 3):

`x` is not an array, it's just an object. (**The console shows it in array format, that's the problem of implementation of the console.**)

```
var x = {length:3, '0':'foo', '1':'bar','2':'f', splice:function(){}};
console.log(typeof x); // object
```

**Just use firebug as the example, take a look at the firebug's source code, and you will see why the console thought it as an array.**

```
//...
isArray: function(obj, win)
{
    if (mightBeArray(obj, win))
    {
        if (!obj)
            return false;
        // do this first to avoid security 1000 errors
        else if (obj instanceof Ci.nsIDOMHistory)
            return false;
        // do this first to avoid exceptions
        else if (obj.toString && obj.toString() === "[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]")
            return false;
        else if (isFinite(obj.length) && typeof obj.splice === "function")
            return true;
        else if (Arr.isArray(obj))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
},
// ...
```

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.apply(x)
"[object Object]" is better IMHO

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = {length:3, '0':'foo', '1':'bar','2':'f', splice:function(){}}
```

*looks* like an array but *isn't*. If you try `x.forEach(function(e){...})` it fails but if you do `[1,2,3].forEach(function(e){...})`.

If you want to create an *actual* array through the literal object notation, you could do

```
var x = {length:3, ... , __proto__:Array.prototype}
```

Note, however, an object created like this *still* won't update it's `length` property on write.

Objects that have a length and numeric indexes are called *pseudo-arrays* is Javascript. An example of these is the jQuery object.

The **Chrome console** *displays* objects with a `length` and `splice` as arrays but that doesn't mean they *are* arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The created object is *not* an array, but it will behave as one (immutable though) because it has a length field and a `splice` method.

In a JavaScript Array the `length` field is automatically updated when the array is updated. This will not be the case for your object. In your object, the `length` field will remain `3` no matter what the object contains.
This is also the reason why things no longer work when you change the indices to 0,1,3. In this case the length field should have been `4` rather than `3`. Since the value is `3` the iteration will stop after index 2 which is indeed undefined since you didn't set a value for index 2...

Comment: What makes you believe the resulting array is immutable?

Comment: Well, it isn't immutable as an object as such, but the `splice` function won't do anything and none of the mutation functions for Array are available. That's what I mean...